# array_rand() array to string?

Tags: php, arrays, random, implode

I have an array, such like:

```
$hex = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f");
```

I want to return 6 random elements as a string (eg. 1a3564):

```
$random_color = array_rand($hex,6);
```

I thought imploding $random_color would do the trick:

```
echo implode($random_color);
```

But array_rand() stores positions of elements in parent array, not this array elements, so I get something like:

`259111213` instead of `259bcd`.

I know this does exactly what I want:

```
echo $hex[$random_color[0]];
echo $hex[$random_color[1]];
echo $hex[$random_color[2]];
echo $hex[$random_color[3]];
echo $hex[$random_color[4]];
echo $hex[$random_color[5]];
```

But:

- is there any way to store array elements within array_rand()? Why it stores elements' positions instead of elements in the first place?
- what's the best way to do what I want to achieve?
- why does array_rand() NEVER choose a letter as the first element, and almost never as the second/third (99% of generated colors look like 11111a 12345c 123456)?

Comment: "what's the best way to do what I want to achieve?" [What's that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @outis From the question "I want to return 6 random elements as a string (eg. 1a3564):"

Comment: @Michael: that's not the overarching goal. Did you read the linked page?

Comment: @outis: how can i randomly generate a Hex color string :-)

Comment: @Rufinus: there's still some things left out. For example, why can't there be repetitions of digits? Knowing the overall goal (what the colors are actually used for) would help quit e abit.

Comment: @outis Without clarification from the OP, it's impossible to know if that is the overarching goal or not.

Comment: @MichaelMior: "generating a random hex color string" can't be the overarching goal; it's an implementation issue. An overarching goal is the real-world problem that someone is trying to solve programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a random web-safe hex code with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614530/generating-a-random-web-safe-hex-code-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are close try this:

```
$hex = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f");
shuffle($hex);

echo sub_str(implode('',$hex),0,6);
```

Comment: Shuffle won't return repeated values.

Comment: i know, but to be honest it wasnt part of the question. the real question would be "how to generate hex colors randomly" anyway, to which @Timur gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since the items are all different, you can turn them into keys rather than values, then use `array_rand` on the result:

```
implode('', array_rand(array_flip($hex), 6));
```

However, there may be a better way of achieving your overall goal. For example, if the overall goal allows for repetitions of digits, simply generate a random number from 0 through 0xFFFFFF and [convert to a hex string](http://php.net/dechex):

```
dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
```

1. > Why it stores elements' positions instead of elements in the first place?

   From the manual page:

   > This is done so that you can pick random keys as well as values out of the array.
2. > why does array_rand() NEVER choose a letter as the first element, and almost never as the second/third (99% of generated colors look like 11111a 12345c 123456)?

   `array_rand` uses [`rand`](http://php.net/rand) ([`php_rand`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/rand.c?revision=321634&view=markup#l63), in the C source). Depending on your system, `php_rand` is [`rand`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand), [`random`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/random) or [`lrand48`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lrand48). `rand` is a particularly poor random number generator.

Answer (score 5):

Random colors should be generated in simplier way:

```
printf('%02x%02x%02x',mt_rand(0,255),mt_rand(0,255),mt_rand(0,255));
```

or

```
printf('%06x',mt_rand(0,16777215));
```

If you need to save color to variable, use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) instead of [`printf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

Answer (score 3):

`array_rand()` returns the *keys* of the randomly picked elements ([see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), section **Return Values**).

In order for it to work as expected, use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to retrieve the keys:

```
$random_color = array_rand(array_flip($hex), 6);
```

As for the "strange" results where there are almost no letters first elements, [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/DdOxv) and [my server](http://perfect-co.de/misc/array_rand.php) seem to reproduce these findings. A local machine running in my office (still running Debian etch / PHP 5.2.9) seems to disagree and evenly distribute elements from `$hex`... Seems to be a PHP version thing?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to maintain the order of the `$hex` array, you could substitute this with [shuffle()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php). Something like this ([codepad example](http://codepad.org/xO3awayX)):

```
<?php
$hex = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f");
shuffle($hex);
echo implode(array_slice($hex, 0, 6));
```

Comment: Shuffle won't return repeated values.

Comment: @jjmontes Excellent point, but neither will `array_rand()` which is what he was initially using, nor did he say it was a requirement

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for taking the time to explain that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a random string of hex digits, you could also do something like

```
substr(md5(time()),-6);
```

or

```
substr(md5(uniqid()),-6);
```

You would get similar results without having to mess with the array.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that this method has the same probability for every colour.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to store array elements within array_rand()? Why it
>   stores elements' positions instead of elements in the first place?

According to [array_rand documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), it returns the array 'keys', not the 'values'. Since your array is not an associative array, the keys are numbers. You'd need to do (untested):

```
$result = "";
$random_color = array_rand($hex, 6);
foreach ($random_color as $randomIndex) {
  $result = $result . $hex[$randomIndex];
}
```

**Don't use array shuffle or array_rand** because elements cannot repeat with that approach. That's not what you are trying to do.

> what's the best way to do what I want to achieve?

If you want to generate a random color, you can use:

```
$color = '';
while(strlen($c) < 6) {
    $color .= sprintf("%02X", mt_rand(0, 255));
}
```

> why does array_rand() NEVER choose a letter as the first element, and
>   almost never as the second/third (99% of generated colors look like
>   11111a 12345c 123456)?

You may need to [initialize the random numbers generator](http://www.php.net/mt_srand), but this is just a guess (see Timur's comment to this answer).

```
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php - as of PHP 4.2.0, `The random number generator is seeded automatically.`

Comment: Thanks Timur, updating the answer as per your comment.

Comment: `array_shuffle()` isn't a function. `shuffle()`, however, is.