# html bullets data from mysql ul list with 3 diff colors

Tags: html, css, mysql, html-lists

actually i am getting data from MySql and willing to make a ul list in php page with differant colors each line of data 
i used a method from css its working but i need diff colors for each row

for example if i echo from mysql data it comes like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6cV1.jpg

but i need 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLI81.jpg

like repeat the list as much it comes from mysql database

Comment: Hello , please post your code .

Comment: <li><a href="#"> <span class="bullet"></span><span class="txt clr1" style="width:200px;">కెసిఆర్ ని కలిసిన ప్రకాశ్ రాజ్! </span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"> <span class="bullet"></span><span class="txt clr2" style="width:200px;">మాజీ ప్రధానితో ఓవైసీ  దోస్తీ..</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"> <span class="bullet"></span><span class="txt clr3" style="width:200px;">ఈరోజు కూడా చర్చ కు రాని అవిశ్వాసం!</span></a></li>

Comment: $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM lt_news ORDER BY userID DESC');
 $stmt->execute();
 
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
 {
  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   extract($row);
   ?>
<li><a href="#"> <span class="bullet"></span><span class="txt clr1" style="width:200px;"><?php echo $userName ; ?></span></a></li>

<?php
  }
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="alert alert-warning">
             <span class="sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
 }
 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Add to you css the following:

```
color-yellow
{
  color:yellow;
}

color-blue
{
  color:blue;
}
```

etc..

Add to your code the following algorithm:

```
i=0
while reading rows , i++
normal html code until <span class="txt clr1" style="width:200px;">
if(i%1 ==0)
<span class="txt clr1 color-yellow" style="width:200px;">
else if(i%2 ==0)
<span class="txt clr1 color-red" style="width:200px;">
etc...
```

this will alternate between colors

otherwise if you would like a random color then you could refer to this link:
[Generating a random hex color code with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614530/generating-a-random-hex-color-code-with-php)

Get a random color and then apply it to your html.

Comment: i=0
while reading rows , i++   ?>
<li><a href="#"> <span class="bullet"></span><span class="txt clr1" style="width:200px;"><?php echo $userName ; ?></span></a></li>
<?php if(i%1 ==0)   ?>
<li><a href="#"> <span class="bullet"></span><span class="txt clr2" style="width:200px;"><?php echo $userName ; ?></span></a></li>
<?php  else if(i%2 ==0) ?>
<li><a href="#"> <span class="bullet"></span><span class="txt clr3" style="width:200px;"><?php echo $userName ; ?></span></a></li>

Comment: =0 while reading rows , i++  this is algorithm , just hints to help you write the code , it is not the actual syntax