# I have more than one article (post) how to make each article its own color or between unit and unit?

Tags: wordpress, post

Hello to anyone who works on Wordpress I have the following question: I have more than one article (post) how to make each article its own color or between unit and unit?

Comment: Use css: `background-color: #123123123` and generate code according to content of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901154/7224402) into functions.php:

```
function rand_color() {
    return sprintf('#%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
}
```

and then use it in your template:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$color = rand_color(); 

?>

// Code for rendering the post.
// Style with $color where needed.

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: this error   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\brs\kareem\Homepage\home-form77.php on line 188